# Prove that the expression is Independent of theta

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that $2\sin^2 \theta +4 \cos(\theta + \alpha ) \sin \alpha \sin \theta +\cos(2(\theta + \alpha))$ is independent of $\theta$.
How do we solve such problems ?

Comment: is $\cos 2(\theta+\alpha) = \cos^2(\theta+\alpha)$ or $\cos(2(\theta+\alpha))$?

Comment: Why did you try and/or where are you stuck ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$2\sin^2\theta+4\sin\alpha\sin\theta\cos(\theta+\alpha)+\cos(2\theta+2\alpha)$$
$$=2\sin^2\theta+4\sin\alpha\sin\theta(\cos\theta\cos\alpha-\sin\theta\sin\alpha)+\cos2\theta\cos2\alpha-\sin2\theta\sin2\alpha$$
$$=2\sin^2\theta+4\sin\alpha\cos\alpha\sin\theta\cos\theta-4\sin^2\alpha\sin^2\theta+(1-2\sin^2\theta)(1-2\sin^2\alpha)-4\sin\alpha\cos\alpha\sin\theta\cos\theta$$
$$=2\sin^2\theta-4\sin^2\alpha\sin^2\theta+1-2\sin^2\alpha-2\sin^2\theta+4\sin^2\alpha\sin^2\theta$$
$$=1-2\sin^2\alpha=\cos2\alpha.$$

Answer (score 2):

As $\displaystyle 2\sin\alpha\sin\theta=\cos(\alpha-\theta)-\cos(\alpha+\theta),$

$$4\cos(\alpha+\theta)\sin\alpha\sin\theta$$

$$=2\cos(\alpha+\theta)[\cos(\alpha-\theta)-\cos(\alpha+\theta)]$$

$$=\cos2\theta+\cos2\alpha-2\cos^2(\alpha+\theta)$$

$$=1-2\sin^2\theta+\cos2\alpha-[1+\cos2(\alpha+\theta)]$$

Hope you can take it home from here.

**Reference** : [Werner's formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html)